# Dashes instead of "to" in mapinfo thematic legend

Tags: mapinfo, legend, thematic-map

The thematic legends for ranges are automatically set to the word "to", for example "10 to 20" "20 to 30" etc. I need to write it with a dash instead: "10-20", "20-30". Can I change the default settings somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to change it like that, but you have some options that might help.

**1.**

Create thematic map and populate all fields in **Customize Legend** dialog

[image]

Then save this theme as a template with ***Save Customized Legend Text*** checked:

[image]

and then, when you use this template later, you must check ***Use Customized Legend Text***

[image]

Of course, if next time your number of ranges is different (more than you have created in a template) then you have to adjust it manually for those extra rows (it will defaults to ***to*** again).

This could be managed if you have several customized templates with more or less defined ranges in it.

**2.**

Second way would be that you prepare all your thematic legends and save your workspace. Then, open your workspace in your favorite text editor and find ***set legend*** commands and change *to* to dashes.

```
set legend 
  layer 1 
    display on 
    shades on 
    symbols off 
    lines off 
    count on 
    title auto Font ("Arial",0,9,0)
    subtitle auto Font ("Arial",0,8,0)
    ascending off 
    ranges Font ("Arial",0,8,0)
      auto display off ,
      "0 to 200" display on , <--- replace here 'to' with '-'
      "200 - 300" display on ,
      "300 - 400" display on ,
      "400 - 500" display on ,
      "500 - 86.900" display on
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I tried your second options but I can't find the ranges in the text editor: set legend 
  layer 1 
    display on 
    shades on 
    symbols off 
    lines off 
    count off 
    title auto Font ("Gram.regular",0,12,0)
    subtitle auto Font ("Gram.regular",0,10,0)
    ascending off 
    ranges Font ("Gram.regular",0,10,0)
      auto display off ,
      auto display on ,
      auto display on ,
      auto display on ,
      auto display off ,
      auto display on ,
      auto display on ,
      auto display on ,
      auto display on ,
      auto display on